# Formatting a JSON Array for an API

Tags: json, rest

I'm designing some REST style API endpoints that need to GET/POST (get/add) an array of objects.

Is there a strong reason to go with a format like:

```
{"Objects" : [{"Field1:Val1","Field2:Val2"},{"Field1:Val1","Field2:Val2"}]}
```

vs. omitting the top level "Objects" and just using the following instead?

```
[{"Field1:Val1","Field2:Val2"},{"Field1:Val1","Field2:Val2"}]
```

Comment: it allow you to add some extra data that has nothing to do in the array. With the first one you can use the same format for all your response, so you can use the same parser/logic to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is important, is that your data must be structured.

With `{"Objects" : [{"Field1:Val1","Field2:Val2"},{"Field1:Val1","Field2:Val2"}]}` you will be able to add other type of object that have not the same structure of `{"Field1:Val1","Field2:Val2"}`

For instance : `{"firstname":"Tata", "lastname":"Toto","objects" : [{"name":"hammer","nb":4},{"name":"screw","nb":5}]}`

So here your structure is :

```
firstname : string 
lastname : string 
objects : 
    name : string
    nb : int
```

If you use `[{"Field1:Val1","Field2:Val2"},{"Field1:Val1","Field2:Val2"}]`, we expect that in your array, the elements represent the same type of data.